# How to parsing XML simultaneously from URLS in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xcode, xml-parsing

I have about 15 URLs for XML Parsing simultaneously. I am using KMXML Parser for XML parsing.

How can i do Parsing simultaneously using thread. How to handle the responses form that parsing. How can i store those responses in Sq-lite Database.

My code for parsing is as follow:

```
 NSArray* yourURLs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.designworldonline.com/rss/",@"http://www.3dcadtips.com/feed/",@"http://feeds.feedburner.com/MakePartsFast",@"http://www.designworldonline.com/category/technologies/electricalelectronic/feed", nil];

for(NSString* url in yourURLs) {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parse:) withObject:url];
    }

-(void)parse:(NSString*)link {

KMXMLParser *parser = [[KMXMLParser alloc] initWithURL:link delegate:self];
    _parseResults = [parser posts];

     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(update)  withObject:_parseResults waitUntilDone:NO];

}

-(void)update
{
 [pd addObject:_parseResults];
}
```

But with this coding, 
`_parseresults=[parser posts];` is called only for last link rather than for each link.

and i  got response in array `pd` is only from last link & 9 times. i don't know why parsing method is only called last time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use framework will help you very will

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request

Answer (score 0):

Use Operation Queue and then add all your operations inside Operation Queue.

Check out this link ...
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSOperationSample/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004184

hope it will help

Happy Coding.